MudSelect Display Text different behavior when property to bind values is empty vs not
I have a MudSelect with MultiSelection enbabled. I also have a MultiSelectionTextFunc since my SelectItems have a Value and a Text. I bind the Value to the property Values of my Model. Here is a code snippet:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOwyaqmnmhvriTTJ
The above works fine, and displays the values as I intended.
The problem is when I already have some values in my Values property. Then, although it binds the correct Values, it displays only the first one:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYcSkqmRwrdnRwmz

Not sure what the issue is but it works as long as you set the Value property, even if you don't use it.
<MudSelect T="int"  Clearable="true" @bind-Value="localVal"
       MultiSelectedValues="@Vm.Values" SelectedValuesChanged="SelectedValuesChanged"
       SelectionTextFunc="@GetMultiSelectionText" MultiSelection="true" Label="Select">
    @foreach (var option in options)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@option.Value">@option.Text</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    int localVal;
    public MyVm Vm { get; set; }
    
    private List<Option> options = new List<Option> {new Option(1, "Option1"), new Option(2, "Option2"), new Option(3, "Options3")};

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Vm = new MyVm
        {
            Values = new List<int>{1, 2}
        };

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private string GetMultiSelectionText(List<string> selectedValues)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", options.Where(x => selectedValues.Contains(x.Value.ToString())).Select(x => x.Text).ToList());
    }
    
    private void SelectedValuesChanged(IEnumerable<int> selectedValues)
    {
        Vm.Values = selectedValues.ToList();
    }

    public class MyVm
    {
        public List<int> Values { get; set; }
    }

     public class Option
    {
        public int Value { get; init; }
        public string Text { get; init; }

        public Option(int value, string text)
        {
            Value = value;
            Text = text;
        }
    }
}

Demo MudBlazor Snippet

Or with @spyros_'s workaround mentioned in the comments below, where you create a local collection i.e. IEnumerable instead of creating it as an objects property. Then you assign both the local collection and the object's property collection in the SelectedValuesChanged handler method.

<MudSelect T="string"  Clearable="true"  SelectedValues="@initialSelectedValues" MultiSelectionTextFunc="@GetMultiSelectionText" SelectedValuesChanged="SelectedValuesChanged"
           MultiSelection="true" Label="Select">
    @foreach (var option in options)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@option.Text">@option.Text</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>


@code {
   
    public MyVm Vm { get; set; }
    
    private List<Option> options = new List<Option> {new Option(1, "Option1"), new Option(2, "Option2"), new Option(3, "Options3")};

    private IEnumerable<string> initialSelectedValues;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Vm = new MyVm
        {
            Values = new List<int>{1, 2}
        };

        initialSelectedValues = options.Where(x=>Vm.Values.Contains(x.Value)).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private string GetMultiSelectionText(List<string> selectedValues)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", options.Where(x => selectedValues.Contains(x.Text)).Select(x => x.Text).ToList());
    }
    
    private void SelectedValuesChanged(IEnumerable<string> selectedValues)
    {
        Vm.Values = options.Where(x=>selectedValues.Contains(x.Text)).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        initialSelectedValues = selectedValues;
    }

    public class MyVm
    {
        public List<int> Values { get; set; }
    }

     public class Option
    {
        public int Value { get; init; }
        public string Text { get; init; }

        public Option(int value, string text)
        {
            Value = value;
            Text = text;
        }
    }

}


Thanks for the quick answer!
I didn't expect that, so i did a workaround like that:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuGIOAQRptRLXPfB
